# How do you get Option Group radio buttons to work as a group (clicking one excludes the other)?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a bunch of radio buttons on a form, but they are independent of the other buttons. So, basically, I click the button and another button, the expected result is that the first one should unclick, but that does not occur.

I figured out a way to accomplish the goal with VBA, but I feel like there was a way to group them within Access itself. Does anyone know how to group up these types of buttons or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the "Option Group" in the Design Tab + Controls

[image: Option Group]

If you place the Buttons in there and assign them proper values, this will likely solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

James. You should be using the Option Group control. This should do the trick for you. If you have Wizards enabled, a Text editor will appear where you can add your options. You can also drag an Radio Button into the group to modify it thereafter.